# ODP.net (negative int) primary key unique constraint (PK_X) violated

Tags: oracle, odp.net, negative-number

While trying to insert a record

*2,'TEST'*

in the following table

*CREATE TABLE X
(
  ID INT        NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_X PRIMARY KEY,
  DESCRIPTION CHAR(10)   NOT NULL
)
/*

which has these records:

*-1, 'A'

-2, 'B'

1, 'C'*

Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException ORA-00001: unique constraint (X.PK_X) violated    at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck)

Looks like the negative ids are clashing with the positive ones. If -2 record is removed, the error is not thrown.

The above error is happening only with ODP.NET and works fines with Microsoft Oracle provider

The database is Oracle 11g and program runs on c#.Net v3.5

Any resolutions / fixes?

PS: The above data & names are samples. Also, the above depicts the actual requirement in terms of table designs etc. so please do not suggest changes in these.

Comment: Negative number is not an issue. If so it could have failed to insert record with ID=1